# XMLHTTPRequest and HTTP "Content-Location" header

Tags: jquery, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

I run XMLHTTPRequest Asynchronously (true) to download some big images and based on the Content-Location information, which is the image filename, my script knows which < IMG > tag it should put the image.

This works if I don't specify the filename extension in the url. If I put full filename + the extension of the image in the url GET, the web server would not reply the Content-Location.

How to force the web server to always return me the Content-Location?

Thanks
Halomoan

Comment: Why would you use ajax to download images, that functionality has sort of been built in to browsers since the eighties ?

Answer (score 0):

> How to force the web server to always return me the Content-Location?

You don't. If the server doesn't send that header, the content is available on the requested URL.

Comment: Ok. So there is no way, on the client side, to ask for Content-Location in the reply header. Thanks.

Comment: @user2168147 If the server doesn't send a content-location header, you may assume the request-url **is** the content-location. If you explain the real problem you're having, perhaps the answers will be more satisfying.